# Is it possible to print variables and change them consequently in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
all: print1 print2 

world=world1
print1:
    @echo $(world)

world=world2
print2:
    @echo $(world)

.PHONY: all print1 print2
```

When running with `make` I expected to get:

```
world1
world2
```

But I got:

```
world2
world2
```

Is it possible to get the expected output only with the variable `world`?

Comment: Short answer: no. Are you exploring Make, or do you have a purpose in mind?

Comment: @Beta yes, I want to run different models (targets) but they have common arguments name like `$(num_layers)` but depending on the target it should be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) were made for this.

```
print1: world=world1
print1:
    @echo $(world)

print2: world=world2
print2:
    @echo $(world)
```

And if the recipes are identical, you can combine the rules:

```
print1: world=world1
print2: world=world2

print1 print2:
    @echo $(world)
```

Comment: Is it possible to set multiple variables at once like this:
```print1:
     var1=var1
     var2=var2
```

Comment: @KenenbekArzymatov: No, but you can put `print1: var1=var1` in one line and `print1: var2=var2` in another.